# Domain of the function $f(z) = \sqrt{z^2 -1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

What will be the domain of the function $f(z) = \sqrt{z^2 -1}$?

My answers are: $(-\infty, -1] \cup [1, \infty)$ OR $\mathbb{R} - \lbrace1>x\rbrace$ OR $\mathbb {R}$, such that $z \nless 1$.

Comment: R-{-1\le x \le 1}

Comment: what have you commented? I can't understand the notation.

Comment: $f$ is defined on the set of real numbers $z$ such that $z^2-1\geq 0$. Can you solve this inequality?

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match MSE quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. Making these improvements will attract more appropriate answers and make the question more valuable for future MSE visitors.

Comment: In the second and third versions of your answers, presumeably you are missing some absolute value signs.

Comment: @Kasper: I do not understand what you find so bad about this problem. The OP has asked a question, and has shown that they have given some thought to it...

Comment: (Although I suppose that should really be directed at those voting to close - it seems you have not voted to close, but that is only through some possibly dodgy numbers...)

Comment: @user1729: I reformatted the post a little bit so it is clearer that the OP has shown work.

Comment: @user1729 I interpreted this as nothing besides a problem statement (and 3 given multiple choice answers). What to do with these kind of questions is discussed here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9201/proposal-discourage-questions-that-are-nothing-besides-a-problem-statement

Comment: @Kasper: I did not interpret this as a multiple choice question, but perhaps you are right. However, I feel that it would have been more helpful if you had said this in your comment (that it looks like a multiple choice question), as opposed to just copying and pasting something which is general and so usually misses the mark...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first part of your answer (before the "or") is correct:

The domain of your function, in $\mathbb R$ is indeed $(-\infty, -1]\cup [1, \infty).$  That is, the function is defined for all real numbers $z$ such that $z \leq -1$ or $z \geq 1$.

Did you have any particular reason you included: this as your answer, along with "or...."? Did you have doubts about the above, that you were questioning whether the domain is not $(-\infty, -1] \cup [1, \infty)$?

**Why is the domain $\;\;(-\infty, -1] \cup [1, \infty) \subset \mathbb R\;$?**

Note that the numbers  strictly contained in $(-1, 1)$, when squared, *are less than $1$,* making $\color{blue}{\bf z^2 - 1 < 0}$, in which case we would be trying to take the square root of a *negative number* - which has no definition in the real numbers. So we exclude those numbers, the $z \in (-1, 1)$ from the domain, giving us what remains. And so we have that our function, and its domain, is given by:

$$f(z) = \sqrt{z - 1},\quad z \in (-\infty, -1] \cup [1, \infty) \subset \mathbb R$$

Comment: Nice My friend. :-)

Comment: Is there a character in Latex for Heart?

Comment: I found it Amy $$\heartsuit$$

Comment: @amWhy: Not sure how I missed this nice answer! =1 How does an problem that get 2 thumbs up and 9 thumbs up across 2 answers get closed? Baffling!

Answer (score 5):

$\mathbb{R}-\{-1< x< 1\}$ if you search your answer in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex).